# Unable to access auth guard user for custom authenticated user

Tags: laravel

I have created an authentication guard for staff in config/auth

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'staff' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'staff',
        ],
    ],
```

I have tried to access properties of logged in staff using

{{ Auth::guard('staff')->user()->surname}}

but i get error

Attempt to read property "surname" on null.

web.php

```
Route::middleware('staff')->group(function () {

Route::get('staffdashboard', function () {
    return view('staff.staffdashboard');
})->name('staffdashboard');

});
```

Comment: my assumption is you mean `auth:staff` for the middleware, so the auth middleware will use the `staff` guard ?

Comment: have you made the staff providers with staff model, is your staff model authenticable, have you made separate middleware for this guard if yes then is it the same you have put on route middleware ?

Comment: ZafeerAhd yes. It is working now with @lagbox suggestion. Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the middleware name to `auth:staff` instead of staff in your `web.php` file

```
Route::middleware('auth:staff')->group(function () {

  Route::get('staffdashboard', function () {
     return view('staff.staffdashboard');
  })->name('staffdashboard');

});
```